# 404 error when posting form data in cakephp

Tags: php, http, cakephp, rest

I have a RESTful api in a cakephp app that returns json data.  I am testing it with firefox REST Client.  The GET requests work fine, but I am getting 404 errors I dont understand when posting form data.  The failing requests look like this:

[image].

If I change the content-type to "text/html" I don't get a 404 anymore, although I do not get the expected response, presumably because the form data is not being posted.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  The cakephp security component needed the csrf token.  Setting "validatePost" to false on that compoment fixed the issue.